Finding a paper that has only abstract on ADS
could you help me to find the whole paper, please?
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1925PA.....33..537C/abstract
There is only an abstract on ADS. Thank you so much.

The reason there's only an abstract on ADS (or really just a partial abstract -- you can find the entire abstract in Google Books) is that the work was never published as a paper during the lifetime of the author, Ralph Curtiss. The abstract is from a publication from the 34th AAS meeting, held at Carleton College in Minnesota. Curtiss may have given several talks about his observing program at the University of Michigan at AAS meetings during the 1920s.
Some of the work referenced in this specific abstract did eventually find its way into print after Curtiss died in 1929. His colleague Dean McLaughlin put together a paper from Curtiss's materials and notes on the subject of these Be stars, and it was published in 1932 by the University of Michigan Observatory, of which Curtiss had been director (Curtiss & McLaughlin 1932). McLaughlin specifically notes that the material on the individual stars in this posthumous paper was taken from the 1925 work you mention, referring to it as an "unpublished paper."
